# How to clean text in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-cleaning

I have many articles like the following:

```
"Ad Darbāsīyah, Al Ḩasakah, Al Mālikīyah, Al Qāmishlī, Al-Malikiyah District, Amude, Al-Thawrah District, Ar Raqqah, Ar-Raqqah District, Ath Thawrah, Tall Abyaḑ, Tell Abyad District, ‘Afrīn, ‘Ayn al ‘Arab, Afrin District, Al Atārib, Al Bāb, Al-Bab District, Aleppo, As Safīrah, Azaz District, Dayr Ḩāfir, I‘zāz, Jarābulus, Kafr Şaghīr, Khanāşir, Manbij, Manbij District, Mount Simeon District, Nubl, Şūrān, Tādif, Tall Rif‘at, As-Suwayda, As-Suwayda District, Şalākhid, Şalkhad, Salkhad District, Shahbā, Shahba District, Damascus, Al Ḩarāk, Al Muzayrīb, Al-Sanamayn District, Aş Şanamayn, Ash Shaykh Miskīn, Buşrá ash Shām, Dar‘ā, Ghabāghib, Inkhil, Izra District, Izra‘, Jāsim, Nawá, Ţafas, Tasīl, Al Mayādīn, Ālbū Kamāl, Deir ez-Zor, Hajīn, Subaykhān, Al-Salamiyah District, As Salamīyah, As Suqaylibīyah, Ḩalfāyā, Hama District, Ḩamāh, Kafr Zaytā, Maşyāf, Masyaf District, Mūrak, Souran, Tall Salḩab, Ţayyibat al Imām, Tremseh, Al Ghanţū, Al Qaryatayn, Al Quşayr, Al-Rastan District, Ar Rastan, Hisya, Homs, Kafr Lāhā, Mukharram al Fawqānī, Şadad, Tadmur, Tadmur District, Tallbīsah, Tallkalakh, Ad Dānā, Arīḩā, Armanāz, Binnish, Darkūsh, Harem District, Ḩārim, Idlib, Jisr al-Shughur District, Jisr ash Shughūr, Kafr Takhārīm, Kafranbel, Khān Shaykhūn, Ma‘arratmişrīn, Maarrat al-Nu'man District, Salqīn, Sarāqib, Sarmīn, Taftanāz, Al-Haffah District, Jablah, Jableh District, Kassab, Latakia, Latakia District, Qardaha District, Şlinfah, Al Qunayţirah, ‘Irbīn, Al Kiswah, Al Quţayfah, Al-Zabadani District, An Nabk, At Tall, Az Zabadānī, Dārayyā, Dayr al ‘Aşāfīr, Douma, Ḩarastā, Jaramānā, Jayrūd, Ma‘lūlā, Medaya, Qārah, Qaţanā, Şaydnāyā, Yabrūd, Ad Duraykīsh, Bāniyās, Kaff al-Jaa, Safita District, Satita, Tartouss"
```

I want to remove the word decoration.

For excample:

```
text = "Al Quşayr, Ţayyibat al Imām, Hajīn, Ḩalfāyā"
wanted result = "Al Qusayr, Tayyibat al Imam, Hajin, Halfaya"
```

Comment: [Possible answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517923/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-accents-normalize-in-a-python-unicode-string)

Answer (score 0):

```
import unidecode
text = "Al Quşayr, Ţayyibat al Imām, Hajīn, Ḩalfāyā"
print(unidecode.unidecode(text))
```

Comment: Kindly add a line or two to explain what you are doing. This will help the readers to understand the answer more clearly. - [from review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32043848)